Is the question about changing ruby text in Microsoft Word off-topic?

How do I change the ruby text language in Microsoft Word for Hanyu Pinyin?

The question asks how to use features in Word related to pinyin.
One on hand, it's inherently about features of some software, and we don't directly learn anything about the Chinese language (so it's fair enough to close is as not about the Chinese language).  On the other hand, the expertise to answer such questions might be found among the Chinese.SE userbase.
Questions about Microsoft Word (even those involving Chinese-related features) are on-topic at Super User.
Question: Is the question about changing ruby text in Microsoft Word off-topic?
I personally don't have a strong opinion about this.  In my way of thinking this would be off-topic by default, but the community could consider this an exception.
There's a few related questions:

Computer setup questions off topic
Should questions about Chinese text processing be on topic?

The answers to both questions have some nuance.
